# Why am I getting Http error 500 when I return too many rows as json in my ajax call?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-5.2, asp.net-mvc-5.1

Here is my code:

```
    var context = _contextFactory.Create(GetClient());
            var r = from p in context.MyTable.ToList()
                    select p;
            int tot;
            var firstPageData = PagedResult(r, 0, 200000, rows => new { rows.Id }, true, out tot);
            return Json(new { result = "ok", rows = firstPageData }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

The first and second parameter to PagedResult() (0 and 200000) are the pagenumber and number of rows to return. This is returning http error 500.

But when I change the 2nd parameter to PagedResult() to return only 20 rows, it's working fine. Like this:

```
    var context = _contextFactory.Create(GetClient());
            var r = from p in context.MyTable.ToList()
                    select p;
            int tot;
            var firstPageData = PagedResult(r, 0, 20, rows => new { rows.Id }, true, out tot);
            return Json(new { result = "ok", rows = firstPageData }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Is it I am getting this error because I am returning too many rows that http can't handle? Or are there configurations I need to make so I can return these too many rows?

Thanks,

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: If you are getting `HTTP 500` that means your app got an exception. Please provide its details.

Comment: I hope you know that doing `var r = from p in context.MyTable.ToList()` means that you load the **entire** table into memory and then return a subset rather than just asking the database for the top x rows...

Answer (score 2):

use a custom JsonResult Class for ASP.Net MVC to avoid MaxJsonLength Exceeded Exception.

```
public class LargeJsonResult : JsonResult
    {
        const string JsonRequest_GetNotAllowed = "This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request. To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet.";
        public LargeJsonResult()
        {
            MaxJsonLength = 1024000;
            RecursionLimit = 100;
        }

        public int MaxJsonLength { get; set; }
        public int RecursionLimit { get; set; }

        public override void ExecuteResult( ControllerContext context )
        {
            if( context == null )
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException( "context" );
            }
            if( JsonRequestBehavior == JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet &&
                String.Equals( context.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod, "GET", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase ) )
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException( JsonRequest_GetNotAllowed );
            }

            HttpResponseBase response = context.HttpContext.Response;

            if( !String.IsNullOrEmpty( ContentType ) )
            {
                response.ContentType = ContentType;
            }
            else
            {
                response.ContentType = "application/json";
            }
            if( ContentEncoding != null )
            {
                response.ContentEncoding = ContentEncoding;
            }
            if( Data != null )
            {
                JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer() { MaxJsonLength = MaxJsonLength, RecursionLimit = RecursionLimit };
                response.Write( serializer.Serialize( Data ) );
            }
        }
    }
```

and use it as

```
return new LargeJsonResult { Data = Your Data, JsonRequestBehavior = `System.Web.Mvc.JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };`
```

Comment: I don't think it has anything in common with MVC.